# Windows - tray icon to all users?

Tags: windows, authentication, system-tray, trayicon

Is it allowed to have some process's icon to be displayed in all user sessions including terminal/multiple local logons, without spawning another process per each session? I don't need to share any windows between session, just the status icon to be able to check service's status without taking additional actions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes can only access the interactive window station and desktops in the *same* session as the process. So this means you need one process per session.

Answer (score 3):

It's not even possible. `Shell_NotifyIcon` communicates with a single instance of `Explorer.EXE`, the one running in the current user context.

Answer (score 0):

I know at least one program that do it - TightVNC server running as a service. You can lookup their sources to understandhow it's done.

Comment: Can tou elaborate on how to use TightVNC?

Comment: Most likely it's a system service + autostarted (registry) icon service to all users. Your comment at least provides an example of the application which seems to work this way, so I don't agree with downvote :3